# analyzing css in IE 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm just wondering if IE 9 has a way to do something similar to Firefox where I can select the "Inspect" option under the Web Developer menu and then see which css classes are being applied to each element on my page. 
I did notice in IE 9's F12 feature, I can select "View" -> "Class and ID Information" but it doesn't show me the css details.

My problem is that my site looks completely different in IE than in FF and I'm trying to debug.  Any other suggestions would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

The specific problem is that in FF I have a left and top margin so that all content is centered. However, in IE everything is left justified. I decided to start looking at the first div of the page because even that's appearing differently.
There are several divs nested within each other but I think I may have found the culprit.

In IE, the css for one of the divs looks like this:

```
#regionHeader .wrapper {
  overflow:hidden;
}
.wrapper {
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width:1140px;
  min-width:801px;
  width:auto;
}
.wrapper {
  margin:0 auto;
}
.wrapper {
  margin:0 auto;
}
.wrapper {
  zoom:1;
}
.wrapper:after {
  clear:both;
}
.wrapper:after {
  display:table;
}
.wrapper:before {
  display:table;
}

div {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
  border-bottom:0;
  border-left:0;
  border-right:0;
  border-top:0;
  margin:0;
  padding-bottom:0;
  padding-left:0;
  padding-right:0;
  padding-top:0;
}
```

But the same  in FF has the following style:

```
#regionHeader .wrapper {
  overflow:hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  margin:0 auto;
  min-width:320px;
}

.wrapper, .clearfix, #content {
}

html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, q, small, strong, sub, sup, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, figure, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  border:0 none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Notice the  max-width:1140px; in IE vs FF which only has a min width.  Would that be causing the problem? Unforunately, this is not my code...

Comment: Internet Explorer has a developer toolbar. I believe the keyboard shortcut is F12 like firebug en chrome.

Comment: I am using F12.  Notice I made reference to the View ->Class and ID Information... which is in F12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebuglite is compatable with IE6+ and can be downloaded here:

https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Comment: Any suggestions on how to compare now between the IE and FF sessions to see which CSS rules are breaking / not being applied?

Comment: If you're having a specific problem, post your code with your question so people can have a look and advise accordingly

Answer (score 4):

Press F12, click the pointer button in the toolbox, click on the element you want to inspect. The css for that element should be to the right of the dom-window. If it isn't, you may click on the "Style" button above the right window.

[image]

Comment: Will it show me problematic css that is NOT being applied?  I've installed firebug for IE 9 and now I'm trying to figure out what's not being applied in IE vs. FF

Comment: A good place to look in the IE Developer tools is the "layout" tab, which will show you the box model as IE sees it.

Comment: It will not show it if it can't read the css attribute. But if that's the problem it should be easy to find it by validating your css. It's more likely that it can read the attribute but screws up the result. Do you have a link so we can look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Hit F12 to bring up the IE9 Developer Tools.

Or select  TOOLS - F12 DEVELOPER TOOLS

Comment: I am using F12. I wanted to get similar toolset to firebug where I can see css rules that are applied to each element on page.